# Is there a tool to generate a parent's DNA sequence from their children's?

Tags: dna, ancestry.com, autosomal-dna

I have the DNA (via [Ancestry DNA](http://dna.ancestry.com/)) of a mother and 3 of her children, one son and two daughters. I know I can get an approximation of the father's Y-chromosome 
from his son. Is there a tool to generate an approximation of the father's autosomal DNA from this data? FWIW, I also have the DNA of two of his siblings. All siblings in this sample are full siblings.

Comment: I didn't know Ancestry offer a sequencing test? Also, what do you mean "approximation of the father's autosomal DNA" - in other words what are you hoping to achieve by this?

Comment: Ok, from the added link I can see the test uses microarrays not sequencing. So there is no way you can determine the father's *DNA sequence* – or anyone's – from this test. What you have are a series of markers (SNPs) that were tested and can be compared between individuals. Are you trying for [chromosome mapping](http://isogg.org/wiki/Chromosome_mapping)?

Comment: Some of the links in my answer http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9340/1006 might be of interest, especially the Lazarus Tool & the articles on reconstructing a Grandmother's genome.

Comment: @HarryVervet Thanks for your replies. Yes, I would be providing SNPs and getting back SNPs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [Lazarus Tool on GEDMatch.com](https://www.gedmatch.com/gedwiki/index.php?title=Lazarus) that is available to Tier 1 members of Gedmatch. Tier 1 means you have contributed at least $10 to GEDMATCH for the current period.

You can upload your families Ancestry.com/23andMe/FamilyTreeDNA results to GEDMATCH and then you can use the Lazarus tool to reconstruct a pseudo-kit for a untested / deceased individual to get a partial Autosomal DNA kit.

It can even be used beyond your parents but in theory a couple of generations away by capturing multiple descendants from different lines.. it will not of course be a complete kit but capture common elements from the included kits.

The minimum is at least 2 direct individuals that are in the children / grand-children range (referred to as Group 1) and contain up to 11 individuals kits and then further generations (group 2) is made up of more distant relations of siblings and cousins of the individual up to 100 kits.

[image]

The constructed pseudo-kit can then be utilized as a baseline comparison as a 'common ancestor'.

For more information you can also look into the [GEDMatch Lazarus forum](https://www.gedmatch.com/msg_forum_list2.php?f=35) (you must be logged into GEDMatch).

Kitty Cooper also posted a blog posting *(Jan 2015)* "[Putting Humpty Dumpty Back Together Again](http://dna-explained.com/2015/01/14/lazarus-putting-humpty-dumpty-back-together-again/)" discussing the use of the tool.

On the Y-Chromosome comment in your question; between a father and son the difference should be extremely negligible (at most 1 chromosome difference) as the Y-DNA markers do not mutate that quickly and even over hundreds of years may only be a few markers off and thus the power of the Y-STR testing. The Y-SNP BigY tests A LOT (million+) more markers which will result in likely some more differences.

Comment: Excellent! I'd heard of the Lazarus tool but hadn't realized it could input the parent of the target's children. I'll look into the references you provide to see if there's a way to add in the target's siblings. (Perhaps I could generate a Lazarus L1 using the children, then use L1 and the target's siblings to generate an improved L2.)